# Decimal points java

Tags: java, decimal

I wrote this code:

```
double sums = Math.round(sum) * 100.00 / 100.00;
```

I am only getting one `0` after the decimal (e.g. `10.0`) but I want `10.00`.

Is there something wrong ?

Comment: @Kayaman that is not a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you intended

```
double sums = Math.round(sum * 100) / 100.0;
```

This will round the number to 2 decimal places.

> I am only getting one 0 after the decimal (e.g. 10.0) but I want 10.00.

The number `10.0` == `10.00` and there is no difference except the formatting.  You can format the String and round it at the same time.

```
double sum = 9.999;
String fmt = String.format("%.2f", sum);
// fmt = "10.00"
```

A number is just a numebr, it has no inherent format.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format` to be sure you get it only the number of digit you wanted

For Example if i write

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum=23.90;
        double sums = Math.round(sum * 100) / 100.0;

        System.out.println(sums);

    }
```

It will give me output 
upto one decimal point 
i.e `23.9`

but if i change the same code to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum=23.945;
        double sums = Math.round(sum * 100) / 100.0;
        System.out.println(sums);
    }
```

I get output to two decimal Point i.e 
`23.95`

But with String format you will be always sure how many decimal you are going to print

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum=23.945;
        double sums = Math.round(sum * 100) / 100.0;
        String fmt = String.format("%.1f", sums);
        System.out.println(fmt);
    }
```

Output 24.0 .. **But it has got the problem of rounding 
So better Practice is to use first convert it into String and then trim the Characters**